Javascript shipping countdown timer not working
I am having a issue with some javascript code on a category page, here is an example of such a page. I am trying to add a javascript shipping countdown timer that says order within x amount of time and it will be delivered on this date. I found some code online but noticed it only worked on the first div element and not the others.
I looked it up on Google and found it was due to the script using byID and others said it was better to use class so I changed the code to use class and queryselector but now it's not working. Below is the current code I have:
<div class="delivery-text">Super fast delivery available</div>

function isHoliday(date) {
    const holidays = [
        new Date(2024, 0, 1), // New Year's Day
            new Date(2024, 3, 7), // Good Friday
            new Date(2024, 3, 10), // Easter Monday
            new Date(2024, 4, 1), // Early May Bank Holiday
            new Date(2024, 4, 8), // King Charles Coronation
            new Date(2024, 4, 29), // Spring Bank Holiday
            new Date(2024, 7, 28), // Summer Bank Holiday
            new Date(2024, 11, 25), // Christmas Day
            new Date(2024, 11, 26), // Boxing Day
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getFullYear() === holidays[i].getFullYear() &&
                date.getMonth() === holidays[i].getMonth() &&
                date.getDate() === holidays[i].getDate()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function isBusinessDay(date) {
    const dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();
    return dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 6;
}

function nextBusinessDay(date) {

    let nextDay = new Date(date);
    nextDay.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1);

    while (!isBusinessDay(nextDay) || isHoliday(nextDay)) {
        nextDay.setUTCDate(nextDay.getUTCDate() + 1);
    }

    return nextDay;
}

function countdownToDispatch() {

    const now = new Date();
    let dispatchDate;

    //If it's before 11AM, a business day, and not a holiday, our dispatch date is today!

    if (now.getUTCHours() < 14 && isBusinessDay(now) && !isHoliday(now)) {
        dispatchDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), 14, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        dispatchDate = nextBusinessDay(now);
        dispatchDate.setUTCHours(14, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    const timeUntilDispatch = dispatchDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
    const days = Math.floor(timeUntilDispatch / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((timeUntilDispatch % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((timeUntilDispatch % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((timeUntilDispatch % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    let timeString = '';

    if (days > 0) {
        timeString += days + ' days ';
    }
    if (hours > 0) {
        timeString += hours + ' hours ';
    }
    if (minutes > 0) {
        timeString += minutes + ' minutes ';
    }
    if (seconds > 0) {
        timeString += seconds + ' seconds ';
    }

    return timeString.trim();
}

function setOrderArrivalDate() {
    const now = new Date();

    let dispatchDate;
    if (now.getUTCHours() < 14 && isBusinessDay(now) && !isHoliday(now)) {
        dispatchDate = now;
    } else {
        dispatchDate = nextBusinessDay(now);
    }

    const arrivalDate = nextBusinessDay(dispatchDate);
    let result = countdownToDispatch();

    const formattedDate = arrivalDate.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {
        weekday: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        month: 'long'
    });

    const finalArrivalDateString = formattedDate.split(' ')[0] + ' ' + ordinalSuffix(arrivalDate.getUTCDate()) + ' ' + formattedDate.split(' ')[2];
    //const deliveryText = document.getElementById('delivery-text');
    const deliveryText = document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-text");
    //const deliveryText = document.querySelectorAll('.delivery-text');
    deliveryText.textContent = 'Order within the next ' + result + ' to receive your order on ' + finalArrivalDateString;

}

function ordinalSuffix(i) {
    const j = i % 10, k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
        return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
        return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
        return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
}

setInterval(setOrderArrivalDate, 1000);


The issue is because getElementById() returns a single Element object. Changing that to getElementsByClassName() returns a collection of Element objects. The latter of which does not have a textContent property.
To fix that issue you need to iterate through the returned collection of all elements and update them individually:
document.querySelectorAll(".delivery-text").forEach(el => el.textContent = `Order within the next ${result} to receive your order on ${ finalArrivalDateString}`);

Here's a full working example:


const holidays = [
  new Date(2024, 0, 1), // New Year's Day
  new Date(2024, 3, 7), // Good Friday
  new Date(2024, 3, 10), // Easter Monday
  new Date(2024, 4, 1), // Early May Bank Holiday
  new Date(2024, 4, 8), // King Charles Coronation
  new Date(2024, 4, 29), // Spring Bank Holiday
  new Date(2024, 7, 28), // Summer Bank Holiday
  new Date(2024, 11, 25), // Christmas Day
  new Date(2024, 11, 26), // Boxing Day
];

function isHoliday(date, holidays) {
  for (let i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++) {
    if (date.getFullYear() === holidays[i].getFullYear() &&
      date.getMonth() === holidays[i].getMonth() &&
      date.getDate() === holidays[i].getDate()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function isBusinessDay(date) {
  const dayOfWeek = date.getUTCDay();
  return dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 6;
}

function nextBusinessDay(date) {
  let nextDay = new Date(date);
  nextDay.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1);

  while (!isBusinessDay(nextDay) || isHoliday(nextDay, holidays)) {
    nextDay.setUTCDate(nextDay.getUTCDate() + 1);
  }

  return nextDay;
}

function countdownToDispatch() {
  const now = new Date();
  let dispatchDate;

  //If it's before 11AM, a business day, and not a holiday, our dispatch date is today!
  if (now.getUTCHours() < 14 && isBusinessDay(now) && !isHoliday(now)) {
    dispatchDate = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), 14, 0, 0, 0);
  } else {
    dispatchDate = nextBusinessDay(now);
    dispatchDate.setUTCHours(14, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  const timeUntilDispatch = dispatchDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
  const days = Math.floor(timeUntilDispatch / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((timeUntilDispatch % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((timeUntilDispatch % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((timeUntilDispatch % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  let timeString = '';
  if (days > 0) timeString += days + ' days ';
  if (hours > 0) timeString += hours + ' hours ';
  if (minutes > 0) timeString += minutes + ' minutes ';
  if (seconds > 0) timeString += seconds + ' seconds ';
  return timeString.trim();
}

function setOrderArrivalDate() {
  const now = new Date();

  let dispatchDate;
  if (now.getUTCHours() < 14 && isBusinessDay(now) && !isHoliday(now)) {
    dispatchDate = now;
  } else {
    dispatchDate = nextBusinessDay(now);
  }

  const arrivalDate = nextBusinessDay(dispatchDate);
  let result = countdownToDispatch();

  const formattedDate = arrivalDate.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long'
  });

  const finalArrivalDateString = formattedDate.split(' ')[0] + ' ' + ordinalSuffix(arrivalDate.getUTCDate()) + ' ' + formattedDate.split(' ')[2];
  document.querySelectorAll(".delivery-text").forEach(el => el.textContent = `Order within the next ${result} to receive your order on ${ finalArrivalDateString}`);
}

function ordinalSuffix(i) {
  const j = i % 10, k = i % 100;
  if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
    return i + "st";
  }
  if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
    return i + "nd";
  }
  if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
    return i + "rd";
  }
  return i + "th";
}

setInterval(setOrderArrivalDate, 1000);
<div class="delivery-text">Super fast delivery available</div>
<div class="delivery-text">Super fast delivery available</div>
<div class="delivery-text">Super fast delivery available</div>




Simply replace :
const deliveryText = document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-text");

with
const deliveryText = document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-text")[0];

